# How to apply filters in Googlesheet API using Java

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an API built along with Google Sheet API which interact with my google sheet and returns all the data. Is there a possible way to apply filter in google sheet and get only the data available to the filter(As like how we do filter in google sheet manually)?

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following:

[DataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter) that describes what data should be selected or returned from a request.

```
{    
  // Union field filter can be only one of the following:
  "developerMetadataLookup": {
    object(DeveloperMetadataLookup)
  },
  "a1Range": string,
  "gridRange": {
    object(GridRange)
  },
  // End of list of possible types for union field filter.
}
```

[FilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria) for showing/hiding rows in a filter or filter view.

```
{
  "hiddenValues": [
    string
  ],
  "condition": {
    object(BooleanCondition)
  },
}
```

[PivotFilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/PivotFilterCriteria) for showing/hiding rows in a pivot table.

```
{
  "visibleValues": [
    string
  ],
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please explain how this can be achieved by using Java programming?. I tried to check in the documentation but i couldn't find the specific class or method to over come this.